# What happens to garbage aboard the Enterprise D?

Tags: star-trek

I'm curious about how trash disposal is handled aboard a starship. Specifically the difference (if any) between one with a replicator or not.

Is there any mechanism to turn the trash back into energy, reverse-replicate so they can recycle that material? Or do they just shoot it our into space?

Comment: +1 for connecting trash disposal with repliction